# Rad Studio Live Templates

Tags: delphi

Does any body know if the Rad Studio Live Template engine can be used in an application?

I have a Ray trace application that would benefit from Live Templates as far as adding objects and materials to the text file for image generation.

Adding custom Live Templates would definitely be an advantage.

I thought the ToolsAPI would be a place to start but I have limited knowledge of it.

Comment: The TooslAPI can only be used to control the IDE and the things in it. There is no way you can use these things in your application. You could implement something *like* live templates in your app, but I doubt you can use them as-is. They are a feature of the IDE/editor and the code for those is not public.

Comment: Just a thought:  I'm not sure exactly what you have in mind, but next time you have a spare hour or two, take a look at the easily-overlooked TPageProducer.  Although it was originally intended for generating HTML pages, it can provide the basis of a powerful, parameterized text-generation engine.

Comment: I shall  have a look at the TPageProducer. I also found a edn page @ http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/37468 for developing a custom scripting engine, so, I might have a crack at that. Many regards.

Comment: Also found a file in the source code called CodeTemplateAPI.pas I may peruse that as well.